# Comparing values inside of a struct in an if statement

Tags: c++

I'm writing a fraction simplifier in C++. I am trying to compare two values in a struct to see which one is bigger, neither of the following work:

```
void simplify(struct Fraction* fraction) {
    if (fraction->numerator) > (fraction->denominator)
    {
        cout << "test";
    }
}

void simplify(struct Fraction* fraction) {
    if (fraction.numerator) > (fraction.denominator)
    {
        cout << "test";
    }
}
```

Struct:

```
struct Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};
```

errors:

```
w2.cpp: In function void simplify(Fraction*):
w2.cpp:40:15: error: request for member numerator in fraction, which is of non-class type Fraction*
w2.cpp:40:26: error: expected primary-expression before > token
w2.cpp:40:38: error: request for member denominator in fraction, which is of non-class type Fraction*
w2.cpp:41:2: error: expected ; before { token
```

How could I compare the values inside of a struct?

Comment: From your last few questions, I think you need [a C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources). Otherwise you're just posting one basic question after another in quick succession, most of which have been asked many times before, which is overall a waste of resources for everyone involved!

Comment: Cool, can you stop commenting on my stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pointers, so you need to de-reference them. You also had bracket problems:

```
void simplify(struct Fraction* fraction) {
    if (fraction->numerator > fraction->denominator)
    {
        cout << "test";
    }
}
```

You can avoid all those pointer de-reference woes by passing references instead. Also, **drop the needless `struct`s**:

```
void simplify(const Fraction& fraction) {
    if (fraction.numerator > fraction.denominator) {
        cout << "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use &fraction. It has to be `function(*pointer)` as defined by my professor.

Comment: @eveo Oh dear. Let's hope your professor has good reasons for that.

Comment: What are the reasons against it?

Comment: @eveo, show him [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf) and hope he will get out of the stone age he is in.

Comment: @eveo well, a pointer can be `NULL`, so you should check against that before de-referencing. Or it could point to the first element of an array. Or it could point to some garbage. You should ask yourself what are the reasons for using it, rather than what are the reasons against it.

Answer (score 2):

You were just missing a pair of parentheses:

```
void simplify(struct Fraction* fraction) {
    if ( (fraction->numerator) > (fraction->denominator) )
    {
        cout << "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: or had two too-many; take out the inner `)` and `(` respectively. `if (fraction->numerator > fraction->denominator)`